# question about Gödel numbering

Tags: logic, computability, incompleteness, meta-math

I have a question about Gödel numbering, it is trivial but I would like to know how can you know the length of an expression through its Gödel number. ¿?

I think you can use a recursive function but I'm not sure which.....

Comment: Note that there is no unique [Gödel numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering).  You would need to provide more information about the particular numbering you are concerned with, though I am pretty sure that all Gödel numberings you see in the wild have the property that $n \mapsto \mathrm{length}(n)$ is (primitive) recursive.

Answer (score 3):

But of course! After all, the whole point about Gödel numbers is that you can mechanically decode them. So given a Gödel number $g$ in any sensible system of coding, there is an effective procedure which takes $g$ and spits out the coded expression $e$; and then there is another effective procedure which takes $e$ and spits out its length $l$. So putting them together, you'll get an effective computation which takes $g$ and spits out the length $l$ of the expression it codes for (if any).

So, by Church's Thesis that effective procedures compute recursive functions, there has to be a (partial) recursive function $f\colon\mathbb{N} \rightharpoondown \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(g) = l$ when $g$ indeed numbers an expression in your favoured system of coding.

However, *which* recursive function this is will depend on your system of coding. But if you use a traditional powers-of-primes Gödel-numbering scheme, then things will be pretty simple. $f$ will be the primitive recursive function that takes a number $g$ and returns $l$ when the $l$-th prime is greatest prime factor of $g$. Exercise: give a primitive recursive definition of that function!